# Stuffing a datetime value into a datetime2 column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Today I saw the following statement in a code review:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CreateDate DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
```

The GETUTCDATE() function returns a `datetime` and is then stuffed into a `datetime2` column.

Does it have any significance that the two types are different? Would it be better to use SYSUTCDATETIME() to create a `datetime2` value?

Comment: Are you asking if it's better for an insert performance to either use `getutcdate()` and convert from `datetime` to `datetime2(0)` or use `sysutcdatetime()` and truncate the extra precision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your column `CreateDate` is using `DATETIME2(0)` for the date definition. Inserting either `SYSUTCDATETIME()` or `GETUTCDATE()` has no difference when retrieving the values from the table.

Let's take your table definition and turn it into an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable 
  (
  ID int IDENTITY (1,1),
  CreateDate DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
  CreateDateSYS DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
  );
```

We then add some values to the table:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (CreateDate, CreateDateSYS) 
VALUES 
  (GETUTCDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),
  (SYSUTCDATETIME(), SYSUTCDATETIME()),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.1','2023-03-30 07:16:45.1'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.12','2023-03-30 07:16:45.12'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.123','2023-03-30 07:16:45.123'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234','2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.12345','2023-03-30 07:16:45.12345')
  ;
```

Let's see if there is a difference between `SYSUTCDATETIME()` and `GETUTCDATE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

| ID | CreateDate | CreateDateSYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-30 07:21:12 | 2023-03-30 07:21:12 |
| 2 | 2023-03-30 07:21:12 | 2023-03-30 07:21:12 |
| 3 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 |
| 4 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 |
| 5 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 |
| 6 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 |
| 7 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45 |

As you can see, inserting `GETUTCDATE()` or `SYSUTCDATETIME()` has no impact on what is stored. This is because the columns (as in your example) had been defined using `DATETIME2(0)` which is the default precision.

If we create a table that has columns using `DATETIME2(7)` (which is a higher precision) and insert different values, then we receive the following results.

First we create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTableFixed 
  (
  ID int IDENTITY (1,1),
  CreateDate DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
  CreateDateSYS DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
  );
```

Then we insert some datetime values with varying precision:

```
INSERT INTO MyTableFixed (CreateDate, CreateDateSYS) 
VALUES 
  (GETUTCDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),
  (SYSUTCDATETIME(), SYSUTCDATETIME()),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.1','2023-03-30 07:16:45.1'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.12','2023-03-30 07:16:45.12'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.123','2023-03-30 07:16:45.123'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234','2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234'),
  ('2023-03-30 07:16:45.12345','2023-03-30 07:16:45.12345')
  ;
```

We then select the values from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableFixed;
```

Which returns the following results:

| ID | CreateDate | CreateDateSYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-30 07:21:11.5500000 | 2023-03-30 07:21:11.5500000 |
| 2 | 2023-03-30 07:21:11.5508485 | 2023-03-30 07:21:11.5508485 |
| 3 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1000000 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1000000 |
| 4 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1200000 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1200000 |
| 5 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1230000 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1230000 |
| 6 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234000 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234000 |
| 7 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234500 | 2023-03-30 07:16:45.1234500 |

> Note:
> The examples used in this answer can be run and tested over on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oTTKVs4B)

#### Answering Your Questions

> Does it have any significance that the two types are different?

In your case not, because you defined your column `CreateDate` with a low precision `DATETIME2(0)` type.

> Would it be better to use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` to create a `datetime2` value?

In your case not, because even though you would be creating a `DATETIME2` value with a high precision, you are storing it in a `DATETIME2(0)` column which has a lower precision.

**If your question were to encompass a possible performance impact when inserting data...**
...then there can be a slight overhead, when certain values are passed to the column. This is due to an implicit conversion that occurs. This can be obtained from the execution plan.

- When inserting dates into the `DATETIME2(0)` defined column you may observe

  ```
  CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(0),[@1],0)              -- actual value 
  CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(0),getutcdate(),0)      -- getutcdate()
  CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(0),sysutcdatetime(),0)  -- sysutcdatetime()
  ```
- When inserting dates into the `DATETIME2(7)` defined column you may observe

  ```
  CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(7),[@1],0)              -- actual value 
  CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(7),getutcdate(),0)      -- getutcdate()
  ```
- You will not observe an implicit conversion when inserting `sysutcdatetime()` into the `DATETIME2(7)` defined column. This is because the values does not have to be converted from one datetime format to another. `SYSUTCDATETIME()` will return a true `DATETIME2(7)` formatted value.

  ```
  Scalar Operator(sysutcdatetime())                  -- sysutcdatetime()
  ```

Following a screen shot of an execution plan containing the `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` conversion:

[image: Screen Shot of Execution Plan Properties Containing CONVERT_IMPLICIT]

#### Possible Solution

If you were to `ALTER` your column to use `DATETIME2(7)` which stores a higher precision `DATETIME2` value, then you could benefit from switching to `SYSUTCDATETIME()`.

If you don't require such a high precision, then consider using a lower value as this will take up less storage space in your table:

> ```
> Storage Size 6 bytes for precision less than 3.
>              7 bytes for precision 3 or 4.
>              All other precision require 8 bytes.2
> ```

#### Reference Material

- [GETUTCDATE (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn)
- [SYSUTCDATETIME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn)
- [datetime2 (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn)

Comment: Amazing answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to point out that [Zikato](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63277593#63277593) and [Paul White](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63276764#63276764) also contributed to my answer as they pointed out two things that I initially missed. My answer is not 100% complete as datetime values are a complex topic. You might receive additional answers in the future which are more in-depth and will possibly provide additional information. We have a great community here at DBA.SE.